# FTPS issue: ftp_nlist(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115)

Tags: php, ftp

Running ftps using php to do a file transfer.  Demonstrating the issue is simple:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$response = '';
$ftp = ftp_ssl_connect('ftps.site.com', 2222, 180);
if (!$ftp) {
   echo 'Connect failed' . "\n"; 
   return -1; 
}
if (!ftp_login($ftp, 'user', 'pass')) {
   echo 'Login failed' . "\n"; 
   return -1; 
}
ftp_set_option($ftp, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false); // added later
ftp_pasv($ftp, true);          
echo 'printing ftp_nlist response: ' . '<br>'; 
print_r(ftp_nlist($ftp, "/keydealer/"));
ftp_close($ftp); 
echo 'done<br>'; 
return 0;
```

When I started getting this error using FTPS, I had high hopes that

```
       ftp_set_option($ftp, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);
```

would fix the issue, but alas no.  But when I disable the firewall, this all works.

What firewall rule do I need to add to make this work?

Comment: Are you sure your ephemeral ports are open? That's a pretty big gotcha on FTP and firewalls

Comment: @Machavity I was hoping that by using FTP_USEPASVADDRESS I wouldn't have to deal with that.  I suspect they are not, but I'm not sure how to check or fix this.

Comment: PASV will indeed get around some of it, but firewalls prevent port use entirely. Even if you have port 21 open, the ephemeral port range [can still trip you up](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/43685/37378)

Comment: I was hoping I could do something like `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 32768:61000 -j ACCEPT` to open the ephemeral ports.

Comment: Updating firewall rules is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add a firewall rule.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d site.com -j ACCEPT
```